# Is there any way to register a callback for a bpy.prop undo event?

Tags: python, add-on, properties

Is there any way to register a function that gets triggered on a property undo event ? 
Just like you can register a function for property update, get, or set events.

And btw, why properties registered in the WindowManager doesn't work with undo/redo ?